# Why won't this Javascript Function Work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JavaScript function that is not working now that I put in a new one under it. Here is what is in the head of my document.

```
 <head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="9j3nz/style.css" type="text/css">
   <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="processing.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
      function isNumberKey(evt)
      {
         var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
         if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
           return false;

         return true;
      }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function stopRKey(evt) {
  var evt = (evt) ? evt : ((event) ? event : null);
  var node = (evt.target) ? evt.target : ((evt.srcElement) ? evt.srcElement : null);
  if ((evt.keyCode == 13) && (node.type=="text")) 
      $("label#enter_error").show();
 {return false;}
}

document.onkeypress = stopRKey;

</script> 
  </head>
```

Everything is working fine except the isnumberkey function that was previously working. Nothing has changed in my HTML. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

I am calling the isnumberkey function as follows:

```
 onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"
```

What might be keeping this from working? It has only started acting up since I put in the Stop Enter Key function.

EDIT:

After removing the Stop Enter Key function the isnumberkey event works again. I think they are interfering with each other some how.

Comment: I don't see how this first function is not working. You are not calling it :)

I tried to call it and it worked fine.

Comment: I am calling it like this:

onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like your stopRKey is always returning false which could be blocking your isNumberKey.

Try re-arranging your parens.

```
if ((evt.keyCode == 13) && (node.type=="text"))
  $("label#enter_error").show();
{return false;}
```

Should be

```
if ((evt.keyCode == 13) && (node.type=="text")) {
  $("label#enter_error").show();
  return false;
}
```

**Update:** There are two ways of using the if statement.

You can call `if` with a single operation: eg.

```
if (true) alert('always true');
// or
if (true)
  alert('always true');
```

or you can call an `if` statement with a block of code

```
if (true) {
  alert('one alert');
  alert('another alert');
}
```

Since your parens were out of order your code was only executing the `show()` if the user pressed enter and then continued processing the remaining code.  So return false was always called.

Comment: That works. Thank you very much. Could you explain how this works exactly? I thought that return false; was conditional I don't understand what it would always return false.

Comment: Its really more about how the if statement functions, see my update

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery, you can simplify your code:

```
$(document).keydown(e) {
    return e.keyCode == 31; // replace this with your logic
}
```

Comment: This does not solve the issue, because it is the isnumberkey function that is not working, but very good to know. I am currently studying jQuery now. Thank you!